# Broadcast Receiver on Pending intent is not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Trying to send broadcast and receive it at a specific time.
RegisterBroadcast method of Class A in which I registered broadcast:

```
cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int lap = 1000 * 60 * 10;
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 5);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 01);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), lap, pi);
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAlarm.class);
pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
```

Receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context cont, Intent i) {
    Toast.makeText(cont, "I am broadcasting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.anarkali.MyAlarm">
```

But this code is not able to broadcast properly. Sometimes it do sometimes it does not why? I am confused.

Comment: Change

    <receiver android:name="com.anarkali.MyAlarm>

to 

    <receiver android:name="com.anarkali.MyAlarm" />

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using the `PendingIntent` `pi` before initializing it, in which case it would use whatever value is assigned to `pi` at that time, which could be an old `PendingIntent` or possibly `null`:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),lap,pi);
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyAlarm.class);
pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,i,0);
```

should probably be:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyAlarm.class);
pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,i,0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),lap,pi);
```

Comment: Well, it's definitely a problem in the code you posted. If it still doesn't work, then there's more, but you might have to show more code, log evidence of what's going on. Also there appears to be a typo in your manifest, check @Adeel's comment above. If this typo is not just in the question, but in the actual manifest, I'd wonder how you even ran this app.